# Object cloning with mutable fields

Tags: java

I am studying about `clone()` method of the `Object` class. I have tried the following example.

```
public class Orange {
  private Double price;

  public Double getPrice() {
    return price;
  }  

  public void setPrice(Double price) {
    this.price = price;
  }
}

public class Fruit implements Cloneable {
  private String colour;
  private String fruitCode;
  private Orange orange;

  public String getColour() {
    return colour;
  }

  public void setColour(String colour) {
    this.colour = colour;
  }

  public String getFruitCode() {
    return fruitCode;
  }

  public void setFruitCode(String fruitCode) {
    this.fruitCode = fruitCode;
  }

  public Orange getOrange() {
    return orange;
  }

  public void setOrange(Orange orange) {
    this.orange = orange;
  }

  @Override
  protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return super.clone();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Fruit other = (Fruit)obj;
    return new EqualsBuilder().append(this.getFruitCode(), other.getFruitCode()).append(this.colour, other.colour).isEquals();
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder().append(this.getFruitCode()).append(this.colour).toHashCode();
  }
}
public class CloneTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
    try {
        fruit.setOrange(new Orange());
        fruit.getOrange().setPrice(12.45);
        fruit.setFruitCode("X1");

        Fruit clonedFruit = (Fruit) fruit.clone();

        fruit.setFruitCode("X2");

        fruit.getOrange().setPrice(15.5);

        System.out.println("fruit's orange price is : "+fruit.getOrange().getPrice());
        System.out.println("clonedFruit's orange price is : "+clonedFruit.getOrange().getPrice());

        System.out.println("fruit's code is : "+fruit.getFruitCode());
        System.out.println("fruit's code is : "+clonedFruit.getFruitCode());

    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CloneTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
}

                    **out put is** 
                    fruit's orange price is : 15.5
                    clonedFruit's orange price is : 15.5
                    fruit's code is : X2
                    fruit's code is : X1
```

Note that I have changed the `orange` object's price field and the fruit's `fruitCode` field after cloning object. But I have notified a problem which is, the change I made for the orange object's price field has been affected to the both the objects, which is the original one and the cloned one. **But this hasn't been happened to the fruit's fruitCode field**

And also when I put the below line it was **printed true**.

```
System.out.println(fruit.getOrange()== clonedFruit.getOrange());
```

I have a little confusion and feel that both clonedFruit and the fruit references are pointing to the same orange object. When I search through the online articles I have noticed  a cloning problem with the mutable objects. **But is it not clear enough for me**. 
Can anybody please clearly explain me how it is happening and what can I do to prevent this

Comment: The concept of cloning is to create an independant copy of an object. You've got it the wrong way round. Also, you probably should investigate cloning vs. deep cloning/deep copy (your clone() method doesn't clone the orange object).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, default object.clone() method doesn't always produce an actual clone. When cloning basic variables you copy a value, however, if your cloning an object it copies the address to that object rather than it's values.

That is why you should usually define your own clone method for your classes (might have some syntax errors, but the logic is there.

```
  @Override
  protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
     Orange orange = new Orange();
     //copy every basic variable
     orange.setPrice(price);

     //clone any Objects that have clone() method defined;
     orange.setImage(this.Image.clone()); //just an example because you don't have 1 in your code
     // for any objects that do not have clone() defined you have to copy each field manually
     GeneticStructure gn = new GeneticStructure();
     gn.setGeneticCode( this.geneticStructure.getGeneticCode());
     gn.setName( this.geneticStructure.getGeneticStructire());
     orange.setGeneticStructure( gn )

     return orange;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The **clone()** method by default, always returns the **shallow copy** of the object being cloned. This means it will copy the values for the primitive type variables and copy the reference for the reference type variables.

Lets take for example, your Fruit class :

**NOTE :** Your Fruit class does not necessarily need to implement Cloneable interface as it is already implemented by the Object, which is always the super class of any Java class.

```
public class Fruit implements Cloneable {
  private String colour;
  private String fruitCode;
  private Orange orange;
  // Remaining methods
}
```

Now, when you create an object of Friut class and initialize the orange reference variable as :

```
Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
fruit.setOrange(new Orange());
```

Then, a new **Orang**e class object is created and its reference is assigned to the variable *orange* of your **Fruit** object.

But, when you call :

```
Fruit clonedFruit = (Fruit)fruit.clone();
```

Then, a new **Orange** object is not created internally, Instead the same **Orange** object *reference* as created above is given to the *reference* variable pointing to it. That is why you get **true** for the following case :

```
System.out.println(fruit.getOrange()== clonedFruit.getOrange());  // true
```

However, a new Fruit object is definitely created.
So, when you call :

```
fruit.getOrange().setPrice(12.5);
```

and then

```
fruit.getOrange().setPrice(15.5);
```

The latter will essentially override the previous value and this modification will be visible to both the object viz., fruit and clonedFruit because both contains the reference to the same Orange object.
But, when you call :

```
fruit.setFruitCode("X1");
Fruit clonedFruit = (Fruit) fruit.clone();
```

Then, a new Fruit class object is create and the *clonedFruit* object here contains the fruitCode value as "X1" only,
And later when you call :

```
fruit.setFruitCode("X2");
```

Then will only affect the *fruit* object's *fruitCode* value which will now change to **"X2"**. But this will not affect clonedFruit's *fruitCode* value as both *fruit* and *clonedFruit* are two different objects

Comment: why my fruit class necessarily need not implement cloneable interface. and when its needed as necessarily?